# What is the next number is this sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

> 26, 20, 4, 16, 10, 2, 14, ?

I have tried everything.. I don't know how to solve this..

If you solve it post the solution please. Thanks!

Comment: By searching this sequence, it looks like the answer is 8, with no explanation given.

Comment: Given how the other problems are on [the test f'' found](http://www.didaweb.net/materiali/dw-filosofia/calcolo/test.htm), I would not be surprised if it's supposed to be -6, /5, +12, -6, /5, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $N_1=26,~~ N_2=20,~~ N_3=4,~~ N_4=16,~~ N_5=10,~~ N_6=2,~$
and $N_7=14,$ and working backwards from

> $N_8=8,$

which [f'' found somewhere](/questions/36655/what-is-the-next-number-is-this-sequence#comment108625_36655), I can reverse-engineer

> \begin{align}N_1&=26~~\text{(seed value)}&N_4&=N_3+12~~~&N_7&=N_6+12\\N_2&=N_1-6&N_5&=N_4-6&N_8&=N_7-6\\N_3&=N_2-2^4&N_6&=N_5-2^3&…\end{align}

… but that isn’t very satisfying.  You could probably construct
equally plausible derivations for lots of other answers.

Comment: This isn't a pattern and absolutely not satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> 8

Because

```
          26
26 -  6 = 20
20 - 16 =  4
4  + 12 = 16
16 -  6 = 10
10 -  8 =  2
2  + 12 = 14
------------
14 -  6 =  8 (N_8)
------------
8  -  4 =  4 (the rest is hypothetical)
4  + 12 = 16
16 -  6 = 10
10 -  2 =  8
8  + 12 = 16
```

The pattern seems to be thus:

1. `-6`, `-16`, `+12`,
2. `-6`, `previous (-16) divided by 2 = -8`, `+12`,
3. `-6`, `previous (-8) divided by 2 = -4`, `+12`, ...

Comment: @Peregrine Rook, for what it's worth, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Will's comment another answer could be

> 0

Because if you

> Multiply first digit with $x$ and second digit with $y$ you get the following sequence: 
> $$\left\{2x+6y, 2x, 4y, x+6y, x, 2y, x+4y \right\} $$The sequence of the differences between each term is $$\left\{6y, 2x-4y, -x-2y, 6y, x-2y, -x-2y,\right\}$$If second term $(2x-4y)$ and 5th $(x-2y)$ term are equal then certainly there is a pattern. If they are equal then $x=2y$ and the transformed sequence become $$\left\{10y, 4y, 4y, 8y, 2y, 2y, 6y \right\}$$ and the sequence of differences become $$\left\{6y, 0, -4y, 6y, 0, -4y,\right\}$$Hence the next term (answer) will be $6y$ less then the term before which makes it $6y-6y=0$

If you don't want to go in details just

> multiply the first digit with $2$ and the second digit with $1$, sum it to transform the sequence. You will see the some pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pattern of my own:

Lets make it as:

> 26(a1), 20(a2), 4(a3), 16(a4), 10(a5), 2(a6), 14(a7), ?(a8)

There are two different kind of sequences going in a single one.

That is sequence of a1 -> a2 -> a4 , a5 -> a7 -> a8

> 26 -> -6 -> 20 -> skip -> 16 -> -6 -> 10 -> skip -> 14 -> -6 -> 8

In between a3 and a6 go like;

> 4 -> -2 -> 2

Complete sequence could be:

> 26, 20, 4, 16, 10, 2, 14, 8 , 0

Comment: Well, the question specifically asks for the *next* (eighth) number in the series, and as far as finding $\mathrm{a8}$ is concerned, you've just found the same thing I already posted: $\mathrm{a2=a1-6}$,  $\mathrm{a5=a4-6}$,  and so maybe $\mathrm{a8=a7-6}$.